# Is it possible to Have a Searchbar in a UIViewController iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uisearchbar

I need to have a Searchbar inside a ViewController as the picture bellow. I don't wanna use UItableViewcontroller. Is it possible to have this searchbar that will help me to query in a NSMutableArray thanks to NSpredicate ?

**My Goal**

After Searching showing the results of the array in the View "white view".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.

You can create a search bar programmatically.

First,Add UISearchBarDelegate Protocol in .h (header) file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
```

Then, Create UISearchBar and add as subview in your view.

```
UISearchBar searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, screen.size.width-60, 40)]; //give your frame x,y and width and height
searchBar.placeholder = @"Enter City Name";
searchBar.delegate = self;
//searchBar.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

Now, Implement delegate methods

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar{

    //your code when search button clicked
}


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

   //your code when you are entering text in search bar
}
```